# Partial fraction decomposition of LTI system's frequency response

Tags: functions

I want to perform a partial fraction decomposition of a LTI system's frequency response, and I want it to look like this:

$$H(j\omega) = \frac 1 {5 + 2j\omega + (j\omega)^2} = \frac A {\alpha + j\omega} + \frac B {\beta + j\omega}$$

Unfortunately, if I use the `Apart` function

```
p = 5 + 2I*w + (I*w)^2
H = Apart[1/p]
```

what I get looks like this

$$H(j\omega) = \frac {A'} {\alpha' + \omega} + \frac {B'} {\beta' + \omega}$$

where the primed constants are equal to the original ones divided by $j$. I have also tried first performing the substitution $s = j\omega$:

```
p = 5 + 2s + s^2
H = Apart[1/p] /. w -> I*s
```

but then Mathematica simply doesn't factor the polynomial. What can I do in this situation?

P.D.: I'm not really sure what tags I should use. Feel free to edit the question to add more appropriate tags.

Comment: `and I want it to look like this:`  You can make it look like this easily, but need to Hold something. Then release the Hold later. But why does it matter what it looks like on the screen? The important thing is that it works for any later computation. Many times, CAS does not display things the way we want, for this, Latex can be used later on for display. CAS is for computation mostly.

Comment: @Nasser: I don't think LaTeX can be used (at least not in a sane way) to figure out the correct values of $A, B, \alpha, \beta$.

Comment: If you want the display to look like you have, I can show you how to do it in Latex inside Mathematica, very easily. My point is that you are asking about a display issue. As long as the math  done by Mathematica is correct, how it displays on the screen is not that important. Issue for typesetting should be left for other software like Latex.

Comment: @Nasser: Thanks for the offer. Suppose I have the output of the first snippet (the one where the variable `s` does not appear). How can I programmatically display the values of $A, B, \alpha, \beta$?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I programmatically display the values of A,B,α,β

For just this, you could do (for the example you have)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
p = 5 + 2 I*w + (I*w)^2;
H = Apart[1/p]
```

[image]

```
A0 = Numerator[First@H]
B0 = Numerator[Last@H]
alpha0 = ComplexExpand@Re[Denominator[First@H]]
beta0 = ComplexExpand@Re[Denominator[Last@H]]
w0 = ComplexExpand@Im[Denominator[First@H]]

Print["A=", A0, " B=", B0, " alpha=", alpha0, " beta=", beta0, " w=", w0]
```

[image]

Compare to

[image]

For more general expression, ofcourse need to make the above more general. The above assumes there are only 2 terms in H.

Comment: Does this generalize to the case where H has arbitrarily many summands?

Comment: @pyon yes ofcourse. the above handles 2 terms. For more terms, one needs to iterate over all terms and do the same for each. The example you have only has 2 terms, so I used that. You can try it for general case. If stuck, you could always ask again on this forum.

Comment: Your values of $A, B, \alpha, \beta$ are wrong. For starters, $\alpha, \beta$ should not contain the variable $w$ in them.

Comment: For reference, the correct values are $\alpha = 1 - 2j$, $\beta = 1 + 2j$, $A = 1/4j$, $B = -1/4j$. And $\omega$ is a variable, so it does not have a specific value.

Comment: @pyon I am not following. Compare `4 ((-2 - I) + w)` to $\alpha + i \omega$ ? and $\omega$ is the term multiplied by `I` which is `-4` i.e. $\alpha$ is the real part of the denominator. I am just following what you have on the screen.

Comment: $\frac {-1} {4((-2 - j) + \omega)} = \frac {1/4j} {(1 - 2j) + j\omega}$, this is elementary mathematics.

Comment: @pyon---Would you check your correct values above? I tried according to: ex5Desired = Divide[A, alpha + w*I] + Divide[B, beta + w*I];  AND THEN ex5Desired /. {A -> I/4, B -> -I/4, alpha -> 1 - 2 I,  beta -> 1 + 2 I} // FullSimplify and did not get the original expression. Off by a sign.

Comment: @PaulCommentary: I said $A = 1/4j$, not $A = j/4$.

Comment: @PaulCommentary: For empirical confirmation, `A / (a + I w) + B / (b + I w) /. {A -> 1/(4I), B -> -1/(4I), a -> 1 - 2I, b -> 1 + 2I} // Simplify` evaluates to the original expression for                                         the frequency response.

Comment: Thanks. Old eyes. Small screen (not really).